# Using SQLite with ASP.NET Core MVC yields SQL Server error 52 (Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, sqlite, visual-studio-code

At the moment I'm doing the Tutorial "ASP.NET Core Mvc Web App" from Microsoft (Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the .net version 6.0. I have the following extensions installed:

- C#
- Jupyter, Jupyter Keymap and Jupyter Notebook Renders
- SQLITE

At the third chapter "model" I'm having some issues.

One of my biggest issue is the database. I need to enter this code:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

after some time it shows this error:
Error Message:

[image]

> [...] Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation [...]

What can I do? Did I forget something? Is that a proxy issue?
I am a beginner. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please copy the text from your console into your question as text, not an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using SQLite, but the tutorial uses SQL Server. The [EF Core console app sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) uses SQLite though.

Instead of installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, use:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

And instead of `UseSqlServer()`, use:

```
options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
```